# Everyone ask ONE expert question today!

Tags: discussion

We're having some... Trouble. Namely, we have been held back from graduating to a public beta for one more week.

Why? Many of our questions are *very* basic. How can we fix this? Ask more meaty questions!

I've noticed just a bit of confusion on just exactly what 'meatier' means - interpretations range from adding details to uploading four butchered cows.

Here's my take on it: We need to ask **expert, detailed** questions. Questions that you would think are *just* out of reach of many people, or would need data to be combined, etc.

Questions that would have an answer which would *create new information*. Questions which would take existing information and put it to use, creating a result that future Googlers might find interesting.

Questions which would require new information to be *gathered* are awesome. Hard to think of, but awesome.

Let's ask what the proper nail spacing is on 1/4" drywall coated in plexiglass, not how to put up drywall. There is already information *better* than what we could provide.

To bring the analogy to Astronomy, ask how to collimate a telescope with a laser collimator, not how to look at Mars.

So, here's my encouragement to everyone: we *can* get over this. We *will* get over this. All we need is for *everyone* that sees this to **pitch in and help**.

There are just over two hundred of us here. A little over a hundred signed up for private beta, maybe fifteen are really actively participating. But if everyone that sees this asks one good question, we can make a ***huge***, and much needed, positive impact to the site.

I'll admit that I'm not the best at thinking up questions. It's *hard*. But we have some of the smartest people in the world here (that's you, O reader), and together we can certainly think of some awesome questions. Your question might inspire me.

If you're unsure about whether your question would be bad, fine, good or awesome, we're always free in [our chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/815/colloquium). Please, feel free to ask us. We're in this together.

Comment: +1 Undo for President of the Universe

Comment: Does it count, for example? http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/400/is-the-surface-of-tres-2b-actually-dark

Comment: @Zolt I would say that's an expert question, yes.

Answer (score 5):

I would like to add, also provide answers to some of the questions being posed.

Researching and writing answers is not that onerous, just go into Google Scholar or something similar, find a couple of relevant articles, read them and write an answer from them (remembering to give proper attribution).

Comment: This comment courtesy of TildalWave :)

Comment: Since it's an astronomy related site, I would prefer [ADS](http://adswww.harvard.edu/) over Google Scholar to find good sources; even though the search engine is not Google's, it is definitely more astro-focused. Digging in [astro-ph](http://arxiv.org/archive/astro-ph) could also worth it (and you're sure everything is freely available).

Comment: @MBR even better!  never knew those existed - awesome, thank you for these - it will make searching a lot easier.